# Spring Data Neo4J findByName(String name) in interface returns incorrect results

Tags: java, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm using 4.0.0.M1

```
    Organisation microsoft = organisations.findByName("Microsoft");
    if (microsoft == null) {
        microsoft = new Organisation("Microsoft");
        organisations.save(microsoft);
    }

    Organisation apple = organisations.findByName("Apple");
    if (apple == null) {
        apple = new Organisation("Apple");
        organisations.save(apple);
    }

    Organisation checkMicrosoft = organisations.findByName("Microsoft");
```

The last line in my case crashes as 2 results are returned and Neo4J is trying to return an `Iteratable`

For some reason, `findByName('Microsoft')` is behaving the same as `findAll()`;

***Interface***

```
public interface Organisations extends GraphRepository<Organisation> {

   Organisation findByName(String name);

}
```

***Node Entity***

```
@NodeEntity
public class Organisation {

    public Organisation() {
        // Empty Constructor
    }

    public Organisation(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @GraphId
    Long id;

    @Property
    String name;
}
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in 4.0.0-M1. It is fixed in the snapshot build 4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

You'll need to add this repo to your pom to get it:

```
    <repository>
        <id>spring-libs-snapshot</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
```

Hope this helps